# Error message suggests that I add feedback but does not say how?

Tags: bug, area-51, 500-server-error

I've got an error from Area 51 "Oops! Something Bad Happened!" today:

> [image: Area 51 error message]

I suspect that there is something broken about my Stack Exchange account as I'm not able to participate in the meta discussion of the Research Computing proposal.

The message from Area 51 says it's not my fault, but I could add more information at meta.stackexchange.com.  It does not say how I should provide this information.

Comment: This usually happens when your account was deleted or merged in the past, Area51 keeps the old data and needs SE developer to manually clear it. In such case more details won't really help, but still, this question is useful for others.

Answer (score 2):

You do it right here when reporting the bug.

Expected information: (one or more, whatever possible)

- What led to the error, meaning steps to reproduce. e.g. you tried to login, clicked something and got to the error page. (Of course the "something" should be explained.)
- What browser you're using to browse the site when the error happened, and what OS.
- Is this happening all the time, or just happened once?

And more, depends on the situation.

Comment: If it just happened once then it's probably not worth posting here

Comment: @Cai depends, if that one time is reproducible it's worth reporting so that it won't happen to others. But for one time non-repro glitch you're right, not really worth reporting.

Comment: If it's reproducible then it's happened more than once...

Comment: @Cai no, I mean "once per user", e.g. wrong redirection once after creating new account. It can happen once per site, but not after you already have account. (Think such bug was reported in the past.)

Comment: Yeh fair enough, I wouldn't count that as only happening once though, but I'm probably just being pedantic